# Why the load() function load nothing of .MAT file when used in GUI callbacks or other self-definition functions?

Tags: matlab, matlab-deployment, matlab-gui

I have met with a problem when trying loading .MAT file in Matlab GUI with the button callback.
The code as follows:

```
function button1_callback()
[filename,pathname,filterindex]=uigetfile('*.mat','open data');
s1=load (strcat([pathname filename]));
```

Then, nothing was loaded in the workspace. What can I do to solve this problem?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In this case, your statement `s1 = load(...)` requests the result of `load` to be returned as a `struct` in the variable `s1`, see [this section](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/load.html?s_tid=doc_ta#d124e871998) of the doc. The variable `s1` is defined inside the function `button1_callback`, and therefore gets destroyed when the execution of that function completes.

So, you need to do *something* to put the data from `s1` where you need it next. If you're programming a UI, you might modify some state of that UI. Or, you could simply push the data into MATLAB's base workspace by using [`assignin`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/assignin.html)

```
assignin('base', 's1', s1)
```

Comment: Can you also just assign an output variable to the function; `function s1 = button1_callback()`?

Comment: I don't _think_ callbacks usually get a calling context to return the value to. (At least, that was my assumption. But on the other hand, as written, `button1_callback` doesn't have the right input argument signature usually needed for a callback in any case...)